# LLDB command line installation on macOS Big Sur edition (11.0) beta

Tags: command-line, xcode, beta, big-sur

I'm using the following command in order to install lldb without Xcode

> xcode-select --install

However, the window that pops up with the progress bar gets halted on task "Finding Software"
Those are the relevant errors I could trace from log stream:

```
Code Block runningboardd: (RunningBoard) [com.apple.runningboard:process]
[daemon<com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand(502)>:843] 
Error 45 setting darwin role to UserInteractive: Operation not supported, 
falling back to setting priority
```

```
runningboardd: (RunningBoard) [com.apple.runningboard:process] 
[daemon<com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand(502)>:843] 
Error 45 setting darwin role to UserInteractiveFocal: Operation not supported, 
falling back to setting priority
```

Any idea how to tackle this issue?

Comment: http://lldb.llvm.org/#get-involved Why not build it from source ? Or download the binary  https://releases.llvm.org/download.html#10.0.0  If not, you can also download CLT from developer.apple.com.

Comment: FWIW, I had the same issue in Big Sur beta 3 (when using Xcode 12 beta 3), and could not get around it. But, I no longer have the issue in beta4. I installed Xcode 12 beta 4, and this seems to have fixed this "bug".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed on macOS 11.1 BuildVersion 20C69 (and likely before now just I haven’t tried sooner to reproduce your issue).

You need to run the following:

```
xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-xelect -license
```

Press space to get to the end of the license and type agree.

Then open Applications folder and drag the calculator app icon into your command line window after typing `lldb`:

```
mike@m1 ~ % lldb /System/Applications/Calculator.app 
objc[17521]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x206a678f0) and ?? (0x1163582b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[17521]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x206a67940) and ?? (0x116358308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
(lldb) target create "/System/Applications/Calculator.app"
Current executable set to '/System/Applications/Calculator.app' (arm64e).
(lldb) exit
```